# Sql query to combine multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

`|Cutomers|Orders|Items|
 |Cutomer1|Order1|Item1|
 |Cutomer1|Order1|Item2|
 |Cutomer1|Order1|Item3|
 |Cutomer1|Order2|Item1|
 |Cutomer1|Order2|Item3|
 |Cutomer1|Order2|Item4|
 |Cutomer2|Order1|Item6|
 |   .    |  .   |  .  |
 |   .    |  .   |  .  |
 |   .    |  .   |  .  |`

I want to have the following table, seems like easy but i have no clue how to deal with it.

`|Customers|Items|
 |Customer1|Item1|
 |Customer1|Item2|
 |Customer1|Item3|
 |Customer1|Item4|
 |Customer2|Item6|
 |   .     |   . |
 |   .     |   . |
 |   .     |   . |`

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would suffice

```
select  distinct Customers, Items
from    YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Stefano, I was thinking too complex :)

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 11gR2, the LISTAGG clause should do the trick:

```
SELECT customers,
       LISTAGG(items, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY items)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY customers;
```

try this, it might work

you can also wm_concat

```
SELECT customers, wm_concat(items) as item
FROM   table
GROUP BY customers;
```

it might also work

for my sql,

```
select  distinct customers, items from tablename
```

Comment: the last one wins the race, its simple and i didnt got this idea :) I was thinking too complex. thanks Ashok